# Binding jQuery click event on a wrapped set

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, click

Lets assume I have several `<span class='remove-type'>` elements on a page.

In jQuery document.ready even I am calling `$('.remove-type').on('click', removeType);`

`removeType` is a locally defined function.

For some reason, a `removeType(data)` is getting called and executed only on the first click of any  .remove-type span. Consequent clicks don't fire up an function. Is this a correct behavior for jQuery `.on` event binding?

Additional info: I do remove the container of the item that generates the click event, but other `remove-type` spans are still there.

Comment: Can't reproduce (http://jsfiddle.net/hrCX4/1/). Are you sure your HTML markup doesn't have errors?

Comment: what is doing `removeType()`?

Comment: try using `.live`, they claim .on replaces it, but with click events, it often doesn't.  `.live` tends to actually stay live so that new elements bearing that class will also receive the click event. `$('.remove-type').live('click', removeType);`

Comment: The issue that most have with on is that in order to make it work like  `live` you must add it like this `$(container).on('event', selector, function)`... Typically like `$(document).on('click', 'a.whatever', function(){});`

Comment: .on() does replace .live(), just learn how to use it

Comment: This code looks good, you have to provide more for us to see the issue, at least the code of the `removeType` function.

Comment: I sure hope you don't delete 'remove-type' class in your function.

Comment: @Jules, I do remove one of the .remove-type elements from within the click function handler, that's true! But other .remove-type spans are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just setting a click handler with `.on()` like you are currently using it. The `on()` function should really look like

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-type', function()...
```

Comment: probably don't use document - use a more local container. for an example, document is fine!

Comment: Would agree completely. Without a wider understand of the code, I can't offer a specific spot to delegate to.